# Tags for "ice" and "icing" should be merged/differentiated

Tags: discussion, tags

We have tags for both [ice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice) and [icing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icing), both have a good number of questions tagged. Should they be synonyms? It seems like "ice" is more general and may be a better primary tag.

Would there be a case for keeping them separate? "Ice" could apply to ice on the ground surfaces, or even hail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [icing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icing) is the general one. Going by the dictionary icing is also a noun. But here's why I'm leaning toward icing:

> **[icing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/icing)**
>   NOUN
>   The formation of ice on an aircraft, ship, or other vehicle, or in an engine.

One of its uses is aviation specific. So I checked the [ice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice) posts to see if they can't have the [icing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icing) tag. I found **only** two cases* that might be debatable.

- [How else can snowy/icy conditions disrupt airport operations?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23920)

This post is also asking about snow but we don't have a snow tag, moreover I think just the already existing tag [cold-weather](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-weather) should be enough to cover ice and snow [and frost] for that post.

- [How does induction ice form in and affect jet engines?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12108)

How ice forms *is* icing especially in the context for aviation.

---

Based on that I suggest turning [ice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice) into a tag synonym of [icing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icing), so anyone who would type 'ice' in the future, wouldn't create the tag again.

---

* If there is any that I missed, let me know and I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1):

They seem the same to me. Unless they're talking about cupcakes. Mmmmmm... cupcakes!